# Can not dipslay textviews on top of the screen

Tags: android, listview, android-fragmentactivity

Hello ladies and gentlmen,

Though I can receive data (reservations) on my screen, however I can not display some textviews on the screen.

```
public class Res extends Fragment {

    ListView lview;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reslist, container, false);
        lview = view.findViewById(R.id.lview);

        getReservations();
        return view;
```

here If I inflate fragment_reservation instead of reslist , I can display textviews,but I can display listview.

and here my listadapter code;

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),list,R.layout.fragment_reservations,
                new String[]{"name", "email", "phone", "arriving", "departure", "pax", "roomtype", "rate"}, new int[]{R.id.textView, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4, R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6, R.id.textView7, R.id.textView8});


        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
        loading.dismiss();
```

maybe problem about getActivty() and I need to use different method calling..

Thanks in advance...

```
       here the photo of the screen
```

[SCREEEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7srxl.png)

Comment: If needs I can post xml files...I have two xml files one only for listview and the other for textviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is with parameter "list"(ArrayList) while creating SimpleAdapter object. Here is my code to do the same thing, it is working fine.

```
public class BlankFrag extends Fragment {
private View v;
private ListView listView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                            ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState){

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, container, false);
    listView = v.findViewById(R.id.dummy_list);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //populating dummy content
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
        temp.put("name", "name"+Integer.toString(i));
        temp.put("sname", "sname"+Integer.toString(i));
        list.add(temp);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.single_item, new String[]{"name", "sname"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.sname});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
    }
}
```